# What is the concept of PUBLIC exactly in Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c, oracle21c

What is **PUBLIC** exactly in Oracle?

Is it a role or a user? And does it have a schema? If it has, can we create objects in it?

I read many documents saying it is a user group as well. But I got confused about what exactly it is.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the data dictionary, it is defined as a role.  You can see this by

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.USER$ WHERE TYPE# = 0;
```

However, `PUBLIC` is special - it is not really a role.  You cannot, for example, `GRANT` or `REVOKE` it explicitly.  And, in fact, the data dictionary view `DBA_ROLES` explicitly excludes it as a role with this predicate:

```
select ...
from  user$
where type# = 0 and name not in ('PUBLIC', '_NEXT_USER')
```

So, it's really a special case, as evidenced by the special code Oracle included in its data dictionary to handle it.

> If it has, can we create objects in it?

It does have its own schema, but it can only hold objects whose DDL syntax allows for `CREATE PUBLIC...`.  That's only synonyms and database links, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `PUBLIC` as a group to which all users belong. You can grant privileges to it, allowing all users in the database to have access to something with a single grant.

```
grant select on myuser.mytable1 to public;
```

Primarily it is used to provide access to system-level functionality or data dictionary views such as `ALL_TABLES` or `USER_TABLES`; it is not generally recommended that you use `PUBLIC` when designing your own applications because it tends to violate the principle of least privilege.